# add java source to ADT eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mountain-lion, adt

I am using the eclipse [bundle for android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) on my mac. I am writing some code that extends `Observable`

```
extends Observable
```

When I `F3` on `Observable` the source was not found. I try finding the source in

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But I am not finding the source. Does anyone know how I can attach the source of core java to ADT eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should install the JDK instead of JRE, you can find a code directly here

http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Observable-source.html

link to download JDK :  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

after installation look for src.zip file in your insall directory

Comment: So I spent some more time researching this, still no solution. When I do `which java` path is shown as `/usr/bin/java`. But typing that for the path of the attachment does not resolve the problem. Also `java -version` returns `1.7.0_25` while the source sought is apparently for java 1.6.

Comment: if you are looking for an older version of JDK (JDK 6) you can get it in the archive http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html

Comment: you can attach the source code src.zip by clicking on the link provided for this (Attach source...) in the view that saying that you don't have the sources where you are looking for source of any JAVA classes. or in  Eclipse Java preferences   you can see this article its provied more detail : http://www.cavdar.net/2008/07/14/3-ways-of-jdk-source-code-attachment-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `src.zip` in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home` I give that up and decide to use the source for java 7, which is at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`. Note that `/Library` in the second instance is not short for `/System/Library`; they are two different paths.